# Change background image on button press multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have some buttons and when they are pressed the font color changes to blue from grey, I have accomplished this using toggle see below.

```
<script>
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
 });
</script>
```

The problem is I need to change the background image as well and this is on multiple buttons. How can accomplish this without making a function for every button? Any help here is much appreciated.

Below is the full code:

```
<style>
 .sportsReg {width: 287px; height: 62px; border: solid 2px #2a2a2a; background-color: #303030; color: #bbbbbb; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 21px; margin-right: 13px; margin-bottom: 13px;}
.footballReg {background-image:url('img/sports-icons/middle_grey_icons/americanfootball_grey.png');}
.footballRegColour {background-image:url('img/sports-icons/middle_grey_icons/americanfootball_colour.png');}
.baseballReg {background-image:url('img/sports-icons/middle_grey_icons/baseball_grey.png');}
.highlight {color: #1ab7ea !important;}
</style>

<script>
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
 });
</script>

<button class="sportsReg footballReg">American Football</button>
<button class="sportsReg baseballReg">Baseball</button>
```

Update: The class should change between .footballRegColour and .footballReg

See below:

```
<style>
.sportsReg {width: 287px; height: 62px; border: solid 2px #2a2a2a; background-color:    #303030; color: #bbbbbb; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 21px; margin-  right: 13px; margin-bottom: 13px;}
.footballReg {background-image:url('img/sports-icons/middle_grey_icons/americanfootball_grey.png');}
.footballRegColour {background-image:url('img/sports-icons/middle_grey_icons/americanfootball_colour.png');}
.baseballReg {background-image:url('img/sports-icons/middle_grey_icons/baseball_grey.png');}
.baseballReg {background-image:url('img/sports-icons/middle_colour_icons/baseball_colour.png');}
.highlight {color: #1ab7ea !important;}
</style>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function() {
   $( this ).toggleClass($(this).attr('toggleClass')));
 });
});
</script>

<button class="sportsReg footballReg" toggleClass="footballRegColour">American Football</button>
<button class="sportsReg baseballReg" toggleClass="baseballRegColour">Baseball</button>
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gKHq5/

Comment: this depends on the functionality. what use case are you trying to accomplish? there needs to be some sort of logic

Comment: So what should happen for example when the baseball button is clicked? Is the `baseballReg` class removed? If clicked again, should it be added back? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: take the time to make jsfiddle if you want better answers

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sportsReg footballReg').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('classname');
})
```

or

```
$('.sportsReg footballReg').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-image':'path'+$(this).text()});
})
```

the second function can do this automatic if the text `Baseball` is also your image `Baseball.png`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass($(this).attr('toggleClass'));
 });
});
</script>

<button class="sportsReg footballReg" toggleClass="footballReg">American Football</button>
<button class="sportsReg baseballReg" toggleClass="baseballReg">Baseball</button>
```

'ToggleClass' is the class that will be toggled of each button

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gKHq5/2/

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but it doesn't seem to be changing anything. I can see the logic but nothing, what version of jquery are you using?